# istanbul highlights wrong lines in html report

Tags: angular, unit-testing, istanbul

I am using `istanbul` in `angular` to check my code coverage. However the reports highlight the wrong lines. Any idea what I can do to address this issue?

*If you want any specific config data from a specific file please tell me where to find it and I'll add the info to the question.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We had this too. Istanbul is no longer maintained and you should switch to it's new version called NYC

https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul (showing the deprecation warning)
https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc (the new version)

[image: screenshot of deprecation warning]